# Match only one URL with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code:

```
if (!window.location.href.match(/\?snake=/)) {
```

Which redirects the user if you go to `site.com/snake`. The problem is that it matches another URL starting with the same keyword and I get an endless loop:

`site.com/snake-mobile`

How can I avoid that? And only match a URL which ends with `snake`?

Comment: You could simply create a substring for anything follow after `site.com/` and match that.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `$` boundary character at the end of your regexp

```
.match(/\/snake$/))
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

> $
>
> Matches end of input. If the multiline flag is set to true, also matches immediately before a line break character.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `href.endsWith("snake")`. It used `endsWith` ECMAS 6 function which is very usefull but it isn't compatible with all web Browsers.

Comment: site.com/blasnake would also match then.

Comment: Well, autor said "And only match a URL which ends with snake?". blasnake ends with snake...

Comment: yup, you are right in that sense, however his code clearly shows something else in the regex :-)

Comment: You're right actually, but if someone ask for help about regex or string recognization, I trust more its "normal" sentences :')